# How to add an attribute value to info window as a link? (ArcGIS JavaScript API)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using ArcGIS API for JavaScript and I want to use a value from a feature class attribute as a hyperlink.
For example, "template.setContent("**Web Address: http://www.esri.com>${Web_Address}**");
This creates an info window with "Web Address" link to ESRI's website.
The web addresses for my features (about 950 features of a polygon features class) are included in the "Link" field. How do I write the code similar to the above example but the link in my info window to point the the attribute record in my "Link" field?

Comment: Hi, this question has been answered in this link [link](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/107038).

Comment: please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
template.setContent(getFormattedContent);

function getFormattedContent(graphic) {
 //format the link here
 var formattedLink = graphic.attributes.Link;
 return formattedLink 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer posted on GeoNet by **riyasdeen_b**

"below should do it.

template.setContent("Link");"